# jquery blind and exposing child div behind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to achieve the effect of a sliding div using the jquery animate option.  I'm able to "slide" the parent div up but I'm having issues with showing the div behind the slider.

I've created this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/fkLYj/) to show my issue.

Try uncommenting the photoOptions div. I'm trying to hide this div so it's only revealed when the parent div is slid up.

```
<div class="photoWrapper">
   <!-- <div class="photoOptions"> This is your data. </div>-->
   <div class="photoHolder">
     Image Here
   </div>
   <div class="photoMeta">More data here</div>
   <div class="photoCredits">
     <a href="#" class="trigger">Trigger</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Code

```
jQuery.fn.blindToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    var h = this.height() + parseInt(this.css('paddingTop')) + parseInt(this.css('paddingBottom'));
    return this.animate({
        marginTop: parseInt(this.css('marginTop')) < 0 ? 0 : -h
    }, speed, easing, callback);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $('.photoHolder').blindToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Current CSS:

```
.photoWrapper {
    width:200px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.photoHolder {
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    width:200px;
    height:266px;
}
.photoOptions {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 266px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser renders elements based on there place in the DOM, if an element preceeds another element in the dom, it is rendered under it.

To change this default behaviour, you should use the CSS rule `z-index`, by defining a lower `z-index` on your `.photoOptions` div, it will be rendered below it.

as [seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkLYj/3/)

Also be aware that `z-index` values may be handled differently for elements that are positioned absolute, due to the fact that they are not rendered in the normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

Using the callback on `.blindToggle()` can achieve that effect but you're going to have to edit your CSS so that `.photoCredits` is visible and just start off with `.photoOptions` hidden:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $('.photoHolder').blindToggle('slow', function () {
            $(".photoOptions").show();
        });
    });
});

.photoOptions {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 266px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    position:absolute;
    display:hidden;
}
```